# How can I add something to a list when a condition is true and do nothing otherwise in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I was hoping to find a better way to solve a problem I've encountered in Haskell.

Given a list and a condition create a new list with only elements which satisfy the condition. Below is a solution I used. Is there a better alternative which doesn't involve maybes?

```
eg :: (Eq  a, Num  a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
eg cond i = catMaybes (map (\x-> if cond x then Just x else Nothing) i)
```

Comment: I'm surprised you seem to be unaware of [filter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter). If you're asking about how to implement it, it doesn't need Maybes, it's a very straightforward recursive definition.

Comment: with list comprehensions, literally what you said is `eg cond i = [x | x <- i, cond x]`. "include `x` in the result list, for `x` drawn from `i`, such that `cond x` holds".

Comment: Just to note, if you use explicit recursion (`eg cond (x:xs) = ...`), then "doing nothing" with `eg cond xs` is equivalent to calling `id` on it. "Doing something" is calling `(x :)` on it.

Comment: ( "*for _each_ `x` drawn from `i`, ..." )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `eg` is equivalent to [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter). Indeed, you can filter with:

```
filter (\x -> some_condition x) my_list
```

If `some_condition` is for example a simple `a -> Bool` function, this is equivalent to:

```
filter some_condition my_list
```

Neither your implementation of `eg` nor the one with filter require the `Eq a` and `Num a` type constraints by the way: one can simply use guards or pattern match on the outcome of `cond x`.

`filter` is [implemented with explicit recursion [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter):

> ```
> filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
> filter _pred []    = []
> filter pred (x:xs)
>   | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
>   | otherwise      = filter pred xs
> ```

Here for an empty list it thus returns the empty list, and when the list is not empty, it will only prepend `x` if `pred x` is satisfied.